# google add is out of div in responsive div

Tags: css, html

I added google add in my responsive div, But when i am zooming my screen it's goes out of div. Dont know why this is happening.
I also picked responsive add from google adds.

Here is website URL

http://www.thewrongplan.ca/

Please look on footer google add.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive google ads doesn't resize when you resize your browser or zoom your screen. 
Check from actual devices.. All the responsive google ads will resize according to the devices.

Hope this helps you..